# lightning-record-view-form / lightning-record-form - open hyperlink in new tab

Tags: lightning-record-form

These forms are pretty nice as they take away so much of grunt work out of the way and lets you have a nice form in minutes.

However, I'd like to customise URL behaviour so my users wouldn't accidentally navigate away from the app.

Pretty basic example

```
<lightning-record-view-form object-api-name="Opportunity" record-id={oppId}>
    <lightning-output-field field-name="Account">
    </lightning-output-field>
</lightning-record-view-form>
```

There are nothing in `lightning-output-field` that allows to specifying _target, which IMO is one of the most basic settings.